# Mysqli error connecting database using mac preinstalled php not with xampp

Tags: php, mysql, macos

Though every credentials is correct it shows error connecting database, using macOS i am not using xampp , using pre installed php and only downloaded mysql if i fetch data from database by typing it manually it shows my data to my site but i cannot figure it out why is this happening , here is the code for database., cannot login to system because of this error.

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "dbname";

$conn =  new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if($conn->connect_error){
   die("connection failed ". mysqli_connect_error());          
}
   
   if(mysqli_query($conn, $db_name)){
       echo "Database created";
   }else{
       echo "error creating database";
   }
   mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: `mysql` isn't pre-installed on Macs.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Barmar php is pre-installed i have just installed mysql, the  error is when i  type manually from mysqli it fetches the data  but  when i try to pass it from my form it doesn't  pass  to  database table but the post request 200 ok in browser console

Comment: `$db_name` isn't a SQL query, what is `mysqli_query($conn, $db_aname)` supposed to do?

Comment: $conn is variable and is connecting to database and dbname is database name , i have tried the way you have mentioned but didn't work for me